# prevent IIS from applying setting to subdirectories

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I have a website which needs to use a *default* document for the application root, but must not for subdirectories.  I'm using the "directory browsing" feature, but I only want it to work for subdirectories.

here's a snip of my web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="1f200f74-07e5-4681-a275-e9cbc9f1b794.txt" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

I tried applying **inheritInChildApplications** to the defaultDocument element, but that does not work, actually it makes the application fail.  So I want defaultDocument to only apply to the root, and I want to apply directoryBrowse to all subdirectories.

I realize I could have web.config files in each immediate subdirectory, and apply a clear to defaultDocument, but I can't put web.config files in those directories (the nature of this app does not allow that).  (Also, **allowSubDirConfig** doesn't work here, that would just prevent *processing* of web.config files in subdirectories.)

Is there configuration in web.config which will apply a setting to that node **only** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use
[Location Tags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8#location-tags):

> Location tags are used to specify path-specific configuration as an alternative to having a web.config file in the folder mapped to that virtual path. The location tag for a path is set in a parent level in the configuration hierarchy, and is considered to be at that parent level.

See the example at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

based on harrymc's answer, I was able to get this configuration to work:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="1f200f74-07e5-4681-a275-e9cbc9f1b794.txt" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<system.webServer>
    <!--<defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="1f200f74-07e5-4681-a275-e9cbc9f1b794.txt" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>-->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
...
```

Usage of the **inheritInChildApplications** attribute in the **location** element is also necessary.  I've left my original "defaultDocument" element in, but commented out as a placeholder for my original attempt.